# Google Cloud functions access via https endpoint require site verification

Tags: firebase, https, google-cloud-platform

I have a C# application that sends data to a firebase cloud functions https endpoint.  This app has been working for a while until today.  I get an error that the app now requires site verification.  What do I need to do.  If anyone has come across this and resolved, please help.  I am still searching for solutions on stackoverflow

Comment: try to have domain verified in google webmaster, this may solve this issue.

Comment: The response I get from the endpoint is an html - which when I launch - it asks me to sign in - which I do, but then I get this response back "Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /uploadCOA from this server.".  This is definitely happening at the wrong time!  Any help please

Comment: check this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/websearch/yL1M1vW5hWM/FLmOfppHFQAJ

Comment: Anirudha - thanks for helping

Comment: welcome, I have written the answer as same as a comment so it will help other.